# Ruby Gem installation fails - Error while executing gem - uninitialized constant Syck::Syck

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm using gem 1.3.7 , Ruby 1.9.2, and Rails 3.0.7.

Suddenly, when I try to update any gem, I get this error message:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Syck::Syck
```

how do I fix this?   This worked before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to update your gem system like this:

```
gem update --system
```

and then try to install the gem again

Comment: Thank you! This removed the initial error, and other gems now install OK. But now I see the following error: "Invalid gemspec in ... invalid date format in specification ..."

Answer (score 0):

`gem update --system` is disabled on Debian, because it will overwrite the content of the rubygems Debian package, and might break your Debian system in subtle ways.

The Debian-supported way to update rubygems is through `apt-get`, using Debian official repositories. If you really know what you are doing, you can still update rubygems by setting the `REALLY_GEM_UPDATE_SYSTEM` environment variable, but please remember that this is completely unsupported by Debian.